# Get the number of visitors from script

Tags: php, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I know how to access Google Analytics data with Data Studio or [with Google Apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/analytics) in Javascript:

```
var account = Analytics.Management.Accounts.list().items[0];
var webProperties = Analytics.Management.Webproperties.list(account.id);
...
var report = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(tableId, startDate, endDate, metric,
  options);
```

**But in PHP, how is it possible to retrieve the number of visitors of a specific website or specific page, from a Google Analytics account / property / view?** i.e.:

input: analytics account login/password/website code 'UA-XXXXX-Y'

output: [19873, 17873, 13999, 21032, ..., 16321]      (i.e. the number of visits on `www.example.com` for each of the 30 last days, as a list of integers or JSON)

Comment: If you are content with using v3 of the API then look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46039271/google-analytics-api-get-page-views-by-url/46040074#46040074.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this package:

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

You can use it to access all the Google APIs from PHP, including of course Google Analytics

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
// create client object and set app name
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Your app name'); // name of your app

// set assertion credentials
$client->setAssertionCredentials(
    new Google_AssertionCredentials(
        'your_analytics_email@gmail.com', // email you added to GA
        [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'),          
            file_get_contents('/your/key/file.p12') // keyfile you downloaded
        ]
    )
);

// other settings
$client->setClientId('your-client-id'); // from API console
$client->setAccessType('offline_access'); // this may be unnecessary?

// create service and get data
$service = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);

$from_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-30 days")); // A month
$to_date = date("Y-m-d");

$response = $service->data_ga->get(
    "ga:profile_id", // profile id
    "$from_date", // start date
    "$to_date", // end date
    "ga:uniquePageviews",
    [   
        'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath', // Dimensions you want to include, pagePath in this example
        'sort' => '-ga:uniquePageviews', // Sort order, order by unique page views from high to low in this case
        'filters' => 'ga:pagePath=~\/articles\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+', // example url filter
        'max-results' => '50' // Max results
    ]
);
foreach ($response["rows"] as $row) {
    // ...do whatever you want with the results
}
```

Also, here's a guide on how to use the Google APIs:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started

EDIT: You need to create credentials to access the Analytics API. You do it here: https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=analyticsreporting.googleapis.com&credential=client_key. You need to register a project first, and then create the credentials. There are three options: API key, OAuth client ID and Service Account Key. I didn't want to use OAuth, so I used the Service Account Key. You can try using the API Key, in which case replace the `$client->setAssertionCredentials(...)` call for `$client->setDeveloperKey(your_api_key)`. You can't use username and password directly AFAIK.

Comment: You need to create credentials to access de Analytics API. You do it here: https://console.cloud.google.com/start/api?id=analyticsreporting.googleapis.com&credential=client_key. You need to register a project first, and then create the credentials. There are three options: API key, OAuth client ID and Service Account Key. I didn't want to use OAuth, so I used the Service Account Key. You can try using the API Key, in which case replace the `$client->setAssertionCredentials(...)` call for `$client->setDeveloperKey(your_api_key)`. You can't use username and password directly AFAIK.

Comment: Ok, I just did.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Google Analytics API client in PHP.
[Google analytic api client library](https://www.swis.nl/ga)

You can use the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) to create the queries to check.

Code Example:

```
$analytics = new analytics('username', 'password');
$analytics->setProfileByName('user.name');
//set the date range for which you want stats for 
$analytics->setMonth(date('n'), date('Y'));
// it could also be $analytics->setDateRange('YYYY-MM-DD', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
print_r($analytics->getVisitors());
print_r($analytics->getPageviews());
```

The above example used the Google Analytics API client in PHP. It was the first library released in PHP. Six years later, this software is outdated. Google changed the API.
As an alternative you can use GAPI library. 
Above is the example how it would work, you can include gapi class to make it functional.

[GAPI Analytic Library](https://github.com/erebusnz/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface)

Another way is that you can use the **Google Analytics Reporting API v4** for PHP.
You can obtain this using composer:

```
composer require google/apiclient:^2.0
```

[Guide to usage of this library is at github](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

Comment: Thanks. Can you give a code example of how to do this in this specific case (i.e. get the number of visitors of a specific website for the 30 last days)?

Comment: Here is the code example to get visitors and views by no. of days. Hope it will help you:
`$analytics = new analytics('username', 'password');
$analytics->setProfileByName('user.name');
//set the date range for which you want stats for 
$analytics->setMonth(date('n'), date('Y'));
// it could also be $analytics->setDateRange('YYYY-MM-DD', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
print_r($analytics->getVisitors());
print_r($analytics->getPageviews());`
I also edited my above answer with the same.

Comment: Thanks. Does your code use this [gapi-google-analytics-php-interface](https://github.com/erebusnz/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface) as explained in [the link you gave](https://www.swis.nl/ga) or another API? Indeed your code looks different: `new analytics('username', 'password');` which API is it? (which .php file do I have to include?)

Comment: This code includes the old google api client class. You can use **GAPI class** instead. Or use updated google api client using composer:
`composer require google/apiclient:^2.0`

Comment: Thanks. Can you add a link to the old google API you are speaking about, for completeness?